# ezANOVA to lme4?

Tags: r, models, lme4, mixed

I have a question regarding ezANOVA and lme4 -- I would like to run my stats using lme4 instead of using ezANOVA, but am not sure how to write the lme4 equation.

Here is what I use for ezANOVA:

```
ezANOVA(data = SG10Long,
                 wid = Subject,
                 dv = Att,
                 within = .(Day, Cue),
                 between = Group,
                 type = 3,
                 detailed = TRUE)
```

Here is what is not working for lme4:

```
lmeModel <- lmer(Att ~ Group*Day*Cue + (1|Subject), 
data = SG10Long)
```

My within-subject effects using lme4 are different than when I run the with ezANOVA. Any suggestions on how to write my lme4 equation using what I have for ezANOVA?

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "Here is what is not working for lme4," what do you mean? What is not working? Are you getting error messages? Have you solved this issue yet?